# I am using "DrawLinearGradient" function to draw gradient line. But the 2 colors that i am using are not dividing equally in the line

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I am using "DrawLinearGradient" function to draw gradient line. But the 2 colors that i am using are not dividing equally in the line.

```
CGColorSpace colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();
CGColor[] colors = {UIColor.Red.CGColor,UIColor.Green.CGColor};
float[] locations = {0.0f,0.5f,0.5f,1.0f};

CGGradient gradient = new CGGradient(colorSpace,colors,locations);
ColorMessage.FontSize = width;
context.SetLineWidth(width);
context.SaveState();
context.Clip();

context.DrawLinearGradient(gradient,penVertices[0],penVertices[count-1],0);

context.StrokePath();
gradient.Dispose();
colorSpace.Dispose();
context.RestoreState();
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove one of 0.5f from locations array?

Comment: You are specifying two colors but four locations. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the Mono implementation has the same requirements as the original C implementation.

From the documentation of `CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colors, locations[])` (that should correspond to `new CGGradient(colorSpace,colors,locations);` in Mono) you can read

> The `locations` array should contain the same number of items as the `colors` array.

In your code however you are passing *two* colors but *four* locations.

Since you are saying "dividing equally in the line" you should probably repeat both colors twice.

```
CGColor[] colors = {UIColor.Red.CGColor, UIColor.Red.CGColor, UIColor.Green.CGColor ,UIColor.Green.CGColor};
float[] locations = {0.0f,0.5f,0.5f,1.0f};
```